# parametrized query jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, parameterized

I have this mysql tables I want to display with jqgrid. The problem appears when I want to display a parametrized query.

For example lets say I want to display all students older than 21. I have this variable named age which I want to pass to server.php file where I can construct the XML or JSON.

On server I see some variables like $examp = $_REQUEST["q"]; but I dont know where to put $age to be accesed in server.php

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually get the answer myself right now ... it's like this

jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?id=< ? php echo $id; ? > ',  and so on ...

The server.php has a line like $id = $_GET['id'], and from here I can construct my sql querys as I need.

This is what I needed ...

Comment: +1 for figuring it out, but it was unclear from your question what you really wanted.